# Почему не меняется символ?

Tags: javascript

Как заменить символ в ссылках?
Пробую вот так, но он просто убирает символ, при символе # все ок

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => { 
   a.href = a.href.replace(/@/, "123")
})
```

```css
a {
  pointer-events: none;
}

a::before {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://@test">
```